# How to adapt #prefix/#suffix for each option in radio form using hook_form_alter()?

Tags: forms

I need to modify the html code of radio buttons generated by Ubercart Attributes. So I want to do it using hook_form_alter().

[image]

If I dsm() the $form I need to change using hook_form_alter() I get this

```
attributes (Array, 7 elements)
#theme (String, 24 characters ) uc_attribute_add_to_cart
#id (String, 42 characters ) uc_product_add_to_cart_form-472-attributes
    #type (String, 6 characters ) radios
    #default_value (NULL)
    #options (Array, 4 elements)
        0 (String, 7 characters ) Color 1
        1 (String, 7 characters ) Color 2
        2 (String, 7 characters ) Color 3
        3 (String, 8 characters ) Color 17
    #ajax (Array, 2 elements)
    #title (String, 4 characters ) yeah
    #description (String, 0 characters )
    #required (String, 1 characters ) 1
```

I can apply a #prefix/#suffix to div wrapping all radio buttons:

```
<div class="test">
  <div class="form-item form-type-radios form-item-attributes-8">
     <div class="form-label">
        <div class="element-inner">
           <div class="el">
               <div id="edit-attributes-8" class="form-radios my-custom-class">
               <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-8">
               <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-8">
               <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-8">
              <div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-attributes-8">
           </div>
        </div>
        <div class="description"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

I proceed like that for this result:

```
$form['attributes']['8']['#prefix'] = '<div class="test">';
$form['attributes']['8']['#suffix']= '</div>';
```

The problem is that I want to apply this #prefix/#suffix to all options instead, I tried something like that but it doesn't work:

```
$form['attributes']['8']['#options'][0]['#prefix'] = '<div class="test">';
$form['attributes']['8']['#options'][0]['#suffix']= '</div>';
```

So is it possible to do it this way? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

In your form_alter you can tell drupal to use your custom theme_radio like this:

```
$form['attributes']['#theme'] = 'MYCUSTOM_radio_theme';
```

Then in 'MYCUSTOM_radio_theme:

```
$element = $variables['element'];


$element['#attributes']['type'] = 'radio';



element_set_attributes($element, array('id', 'name','#return_value' => 'value'));



if (isset($element['#return_value']) && $element['#value'] !== FALSE && $element['#value'] == $element['#return_value']) {
    $element['#attributes']['checked'] = 'checked';



}
  _form_set_class($element, array('form-radio'));

  return '<div class="test"><input' . drupal_attributes($element['#attributes']) . ' /></div>';
```

Comment: Thanks for this information. Unfortunately I was not able to do it this way. I was just able to call theme_radio() from my template.php file using this name: mytheme_radio(). Is it possible to call 'MYCUSTOM_radio_theme' from .module file? How??

Comment: you need to register your theme function with hook_theme

Comment: @2pha, can you give more info about how to register a theme function in .module files? I tried something like declaring two functions: MY_MODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) and theme_custom_radio().

Comment: I think this page will help you to understand how to write your hook_theme: [hook_theme](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_theme/7)

Answer (score 2):

There is an easy answer to this, but I was very nearly driven insane trying to find it because it doesn't appear to be documented anywhere.

```
$form['input']['option_key'] = array(
  '#prefix' => '',
  '#suffix' => '',
);
```

This is counter-intuitive because it creates an entirely new array for #prefix and #suffix, but I swear it works. In OP's case you would use $form['attributes'][0] to get the first option ('attributes' appears to be the name of the radio button collection, not the form's #attributes array). If it were using strings as array keys you'd use $form['attributes']['option_name'].

I imagine you can do some other interesting things too.

Comment: This is awesome, and should be the answer!

Comment: oops, i got ahead of myself. This doesnt work for checkbox options, as you cannot set a #value or #title for the label, and so the ley > label relationship does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could override the [theme_radio](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/theme_radio/7) function instead of using form_alter.

Answer (score 1):

Since I can't comment, what @taburk has said is by far the best option. A note of point though, this method can ONLY be done with a hook_form_alter (or hook_form_FORM_ID_alter) as the form array must already exist.

Also, in your form alter remember that as the array already exists you need to append the prefix/suffix keys to it, not overwrite the existing array.

```
<?php
if($form_id == 'my_form_id'){
        foreach($form['my_radio_field']['#options'] as $macname => $thememarkup) {
            $form['my_radio_field'][$macname]['#prefix'] = '<div class="col-md-6">';
            $form['my_radio_field'][$macname]['#suffix'] = '</div>';
        }
    }
?>
```